# Create a column based on values of multiple rows tied to a key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with customers and categories they shop in, and I want to know if a customer is a cross-category shopper (there are only three categories). What is the best way to turn this:

```
Customer Category
foo      A
foo      B
boo      A
zoo      C
```

to this:

```
Customer  A B C CrossCategory
foo       Y Y N  True
boo       Y N N  False
zoo       N N Y  False
```

Comment: Would the output of `df.groupby('Customer')['Category'].nunique() > 1` already be sufficient? This would be the `CrossCategory` column...

Comment: Thank you @Cleb that does give me what I am looking for although it would be great to have the Categories pivoted as well.

Comment: `df1.groupby('Customer').apply(lambda x:x.Category.count()) > 1` i think you can do this way also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are only interested in the column `CrossCategory`, you can use:

```
df.groupby('Customer')['Category'].nunique() > 1
```

which gives

```
Customer
boo    False
foo     True
zoo    False
Name: Category, dtype: bool
```

For the `pivot` part:

You can add another column:

```
df['visited'] = 'Y'
```

and then use `pivot`

```
p = df.pivot(index='Customer', columns='Category', values='visited').fillna('N')

Category  A  B  C
Customer         
boo       Y  N  N
foo       Y  Y  N
zoo       N  N  Y
```

Then we use a second approach to get the `CrossCategory` column

```
# alternative approach to the nunique part from above
df['CrossCategory'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Category'].transform('size') > 1

  Customer Category visited  CrossCategory
0      foo        A       Y           True
1      foo        B       Y           True
2      boo        A       Y          False
3      zoo        C       Y          False
```

and finally concatenate the two dataframes

```
pd.concat([p, df[['Customer', 'CrossCategory']].drop_duplicates().set_index('Customer')], sort=False, axis=1)
```

That yields:

```
     A  B  C  CrossCategory
boo  Y  N  N          False
foo  Y  Y  N           True
zoo  N  N  Y          False
```

I am pretty sure that there are more elegant solutions, but that gives the desired output.

If you have big datasets, you might want to run `groupby` with `sort=False`.